# UseSuperWord turned off, and still getting vectorized code?

Tags: java, jit, jmh

I am benchmarking some algorithms, wondering how much the JIT applies auto-vectorization. I set up a JMH project and am trying to turn auto-vectorization off.

The code snipped and the results can be found in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/Styp/16e8a20fedfb771107377407fc1cf210 (Sorry too long to post here).

The results indicate that one is faster than the other, which is expected. Nevertheless, the deviation is so high that the benchmark is not representative. What irritates me the most is that the version with turned of SuperWord still contains vadd and vmove instructions in the Jit-generated code. Do I miss something? How can I enforce vectorization turned off for good?
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any vector instruction in both runs, which is kind of expected since vectorisation of matrix multiplication is not trivial.

Comment: `vadd` and `vmov` do not mean vector instructions, in this case `vaddss` and `vmovss` are scalar instructions working on single single-precision elements (hence `ss`).

Comment: This statement is wrong, vadd and vmov do operations on the XMM register which is MMX so, therefore, we have SIMD acceleration...

Comment: In x86, vector registers are also floating point registers, so all fp operations operate on vector registers.

Comment: Also, just because an instruction operate on vector registers, one cannot imply that it is a vector instruction. In this case, the instruction `vmovss` stands for Vex-prefixed, MOV Single Single-precision floating point value, which is a scalar instruction. The corresponding vector instruction is `vmovps` which stands for Vex-prefixed, MOV Packed Single-precision floating point values.